# How to Map a JPA create native query to projections

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get count from a postgreSQL database using Spring Data JPA createNativeQuery. However, the query is returning null instead of the actual values.

Here is the JPA createNativeQuery statement below:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT null AS id, 
count(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) 
then 1 else null end) AS pending,  
count(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else null end) AS submitted, 
count(*) AS totalApplications FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS ", AnnualReturn.class);
//Note: AnnualReturn is the name of the @Entity class

List <AnnualReturn> countList=q.getResultList();

return countList;
```

I need help mapping the "submitted", "pending" and "totalApplications" instances from my query in a way that returns the result as below.

Result expected is:

```
"data": {
        "totalApplications": 2000,
        "submitted": 560,
        "pending": 60,
    }
```

Result am getting:

```
{
    "data": [
        null
    ]
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I suppose you don't really want a typed query, it seems submitted is a boolean field and you want to return a number in submitted. Without the class paramter you'll porbably get a List of Object[] with the values

Comment: I want to return the count as a Long data type, where submitted is "true". So I am looking to create a mapping/translation layer as the entity alone cannot produce the desired result. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `SELECT null AS id` any reason why you are fetching null as id? Can you update it to fetch the actual value `select id` OR simply do `select 0 as id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why but I believe `SELECT null AS id` is causing null record to be fetched.

If you don't want id to be fetched then you can use projection with custom RowMapper or DTO projection.

See below:

```
@Entity
@Data
@ToString
class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String name;
    int age;

    public A() {
    }
    public A(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

interface ARepo extends JpaRepositoryImplementation<A, Long> {
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Init {
    final ARepo repo;
    final EntityManager em;

    @EventListener
    public void init(ContextRefreshedEvent evt) {
        repo.save(new A("XX", 5));
        repo.save(new A("ZZ", 6));
        repo.save(new A("AA", 11));
        repo.save(new A("AB", 12));

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select 0 as id, a.name as name, a.age as age  from A a where a.total > 10 ", A.class);

        System.out.println(q.getResultList()); //fetches AA and BB 
        //if you change the query to select null as id  it would return [ null, null]
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I jus want the count and not the actual names? "select 0 as id, count(a.name) as nameCount, count(a.age) as ageCount  from A a where a.total > 10 ", A.class)... how would I map nameCount and ageCount since these count variables are not in my @Entity class?

Comment: Look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections. If you can represent your queries in spring data jpa queries then it supports projection to interface, custom dto or entity automatically. If you want to write your own custom query then you need to provide manual mapping of fields. If your query is a complex SQL query then i would advise to use `@JdbcTemplate` so that you can easily provide the RowMapper to bind results to a DTO

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a typed Query here, try something like

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT " +
  " COALESCE(sum(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) " +
  " then AMOUNT else 0 end),0) AS pending,  " +
  " COALESCE(sum(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else 0 end),0) AS submitted, " +
  " COALESCE(sum(AMOUNT),0) AS totalApplications FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS ");

List <Object[]> countList=q.getResultList();

Object[] obj = countList.get(0);

for (Object value : obj) {
     System.out.println(value);
}
long pending = ((BigInteger)obj[0]).longValue();
long submitted = ((BigInteger)obj[1]).longValue();
long total = ((BigInteger)obj[2]).longValue();


return ...; // prepare the values to your convinience
```

*EDIT*

changed null to 0 to avoid possible null values in the result

*EDIT*

fixed NPE on empty table

Comment: It threw a compilation error saying I have to cast the obj to a long. After casting long pending=(long) obj[0] for the different values, it compiled but when I sent the request, it threw a null pointer error at runtime, from when it got to the first line : long pending=(long) obj[0]

Comment: you removed 'null AS id', as I did?, please log obj and show its content

Comment: When I removed the column id, it threw error at runtime it said:: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet. 

That is whyI I added that clause to the select statement

Comment: Did you remove the AnnualReturn.class, too? I see no other reson for the need of a column named 'id'

Comment: Initially I did not remove the AnnualReturn.class, but when I removed it, the applications breaks at the line long pending=(long) obj[0] with a null pointer exception

Comment: please use this link to see the log or full error trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHDbE8qaeJo8UE_vPmkIdzdYZeq-m96W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I made a small edit (null -> 0) and please log obj before the cast

Comment: Please I don't get this: (null -> 0)... should I add that to the sql query or somewhere else?

Comment: :-) look at my post, I changed null to 0 in the query

Comment: okay, I changed the null to 0 and removed select null as id, I also printed the obj before the casts object and got this : Obj is  : [Ljava.lang.Object;@241b38c3

The null exception still happens however as previously

Comment: Sorry, my bad, in my test values come back as BigInteger, but the edited version is working for me (asuming AMOUNT can't be null)

Comment: So how do I modify mine to get values that return as bigint like yours?

Comment: Check in the loop what you get

Comment: In the for loop... I get null for each value in obj... and AMOUNT is not null. I also get the same null pointer exception when it gets to the casts and the application breaks at that point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224164/discussion-between-turo-and-kingified).